# jwt is best way for token react?

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone explain a good way of storing jwt tokens securely in React  app

I am new for React and I think storing jwt tokens in SharedPreferences is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you should store JWT tokens in HTTPOnly cookies. When you store the tokens in HTTPOnly, basically they are stored in an encrypted manner, so that the client won't have read access to them.

The other storing alternatives such as, Localstorage, Sessionstorage and normal cookies can be accessed by the client, thus shouldn't be used for secure applications.